# How do I make @> operator recognize my int4range partition key in PostgreSQL Table Partitioning?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Table Partitioning with a `int4range` key.

I am trying to partition my table with a `int4range` key to filter active records to one partition and archive records to another partition.

The queries sent to my db typically use the @> operator which does not seem to recognize my partition key. When gathering the execution plan it still seems to try to pull a record from the `test_part_archive` which degrades the overall query plan.

My production table has 20-50m records.

Any recomendations to overcome this issue?

Postgres 14.8

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (id int4range NOT NULL, value varchar(20)) partition by range(upper(id));

CREATE TABLE test_part_archive partition of test
  for values from (1) to (2147483646);

CREATE TABLE test_part_active partition of test
  default;

insert into test (id, value) select '[1,2)', 'test';
insert into test (id, value) select '[3,4)', 'test2';
insert into test (id, value) select '[4,9)', 'test3';
insert into test (id, value) select '[5,2147483646)', 'test4';
insert into test (id, value) select '[6,)', 'test5';

explain select * from test where id @> 2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use partition pruning based on the upper part of `id`, then you'll need to change the queries to explicitly check `UPPER(id) IS NULL OR UPPER(id) >= 2147483647` (the `>` could be left out, but it's presence protects against future widening of the range type). Partitioning by `RANGE(UPPER(id))` is effectively the same as creating a functional index based on `UPPER(id)`. PostgreSQL doesn't recognize that `id @> 2147483647` is effectively the same as the partioning expression.

Instead of using a partitioned table, consider using partial indexes. To demonstrate the potential performance improvement, a table with 10M rows where ~10K of those rows are active was created:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int4range NOT NULL, value varchar(20), fat_column char(500) DEFAULT ' ');

INSERT INTO test(id, value)
SELECT INT4RANGE((RANDOM() * test_size)::int4 + 1,
                 CASE WHEN RANDOM() < active_probability THEN NULL::int4
                          ELSE GREATEST(n, (RANDOM() * (2147483647 - test_size))::int4 + test_size)
                     END),
           n
  FROM (VALUES (10000000, 0.001)) t(test_size, active_probability)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL GENERATE_SERIES(1,test_size) s(n);

ANALYZE test;
```

The column, `fat_column`, increases the row width as a surrogate for additional columns that might be part of a real-life table.

After restarting PostgreSQL to avoid effects caused by cached data, a query to select only active rows was run:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)
SELECT * FROM test
 WHERE id @> 2147483647;
```

This produced the following explain plan:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..777369.33 rows=100000 width=529) (actual time=1.014..4443.505 rows=10135 loops=1)
  Output: id, value, fat_column
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=16088 read=698254 dirtied=61610 written=61514
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.test  (cost=0.00..766369.33 rows=41667 width=529) (actual time=1.690..4424.870 rows=3378 loops=3)
        Output: id, value, fat_column
        Filter: (test.id @> 2147483647)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3329955
        Buffers: shared hit=16088 read=698254 dirtied=61610 written=61514
        Worker 0:  actual time=2.904..4422.835 rows=3405 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=5538 read=230722 dirtied=20680 written=20648
        Worker 1:  actual time=1.410..4423.583 rows=3351 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=5430 read=233570 dirtied=20860 written=20828
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=38 read=6 dirtied=3
Planning Time: 0.908 ms
Execution Time: 4448.415 ms
```

```
CREATE INDEX test_id_active_ndx ON test(id) WHERE (id @> 2147483647);
```

After restarting PostgreSQL, the query was run again which produced the following:

```
Gather  (cost=1239.96..317659.77 rows=100000 width=529) (actual time=7.569..117.125 rows=10135 loops=1)
  Output: id, value, fat_column
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared read=10098
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.test  (cost=239.96..306659.77 rows=41667 width=529) (actual time=2.480..104.103 rows=3378 loops=3)
        Output: id, value, fat_column
        Recheck Cond: (test.id @> 2147483647)
        Heap Blocks: exact=3427
        Buffers: shared read=10098
        Worker 0:  actual time=0.093..100.372 rows=3452 loops=1
          Buffers: shared read=3432
        Worker 1:  actual time=0.073..103.584 rows=3219 loops=1
          Buffers: shared read=3199
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_id_active_ndx  (cost=0.00..214.96 rows=100000 width=0) (actual time=4.724..4.724 rows=10135 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared read=40
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=53 read=10 dirtied=3
Planning Time: 41.054 ms
Execution Time: 118.651 ms
```

With the index, the query ran ~37 times faster. Repeated runs of the query (without restarting PostgreSQL) produced an average execution time of ~3800 ms without the index and ~24 ms with the index. For the repeated runs, that makes the average execution time ~158 times faster.

Several factors will affect the actual performance improvement. Among those factors are: table size, number of active rows, average row width, and additional columns included in the index.

Comment: Since I am not able to control the query, but I can control the table, is there a way to partition it in a different manner to properly respect the contains operator?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of any way to effectively use table partitions without changing the queries. If lower and upper portions of `id` were modeled as discrete columns instead of part of a range, then partitioning could be used; however, changing the table model would also necessitate query changes. I've updated my answer to address using partial indexes as a possible approach to achieving at least some of the performance advantages of partitioning.

Comment: Okay, we do have column indexes and a GIST index on the range column. I'll keep an eye on the query logs to see if there's another field that would serve for a proper partition key.